# How to set microphone(mic-in) as default using NAudio?

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

i have a question
How to set microphone(mic-in) as default using NAudio?
I have default audio card and "line-in" sometimes sets as default. I need sets Microphone(mic-in) as default. Or how to dicabled/enabled "Line-In" device

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that NAudio can do what you want, and other options seem to involve a bit of hackery.

I used [this project](http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/) (EndPointController) to do exactly what you want to do (in Windows 7 at least).

It builds an .exe called EndPointController that accepts a device ID as input on the command line. The link containing .NET wrapper code he refers to at that site is broken, but [this one works](http://www.spikex.net/programmatically-changing-the-default-audio-playback-device-on-windows-vista-windows-7/) as of Nov '14.